# does it matter where flag appears in a command?

Tags: linux, options

I have been using the following command to install the Expo CLI package:

```
sudo npm install expo-cli --global
```

The command above works successfully to install that package.  However, I'm wondering if moving the `--global` before the package name would work equally to the command above.  So, doing this instead:

```
sudo npm install --global expo-cli
```

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04.

I looked online for a reference but did not find one (even though there must be one out there somewhere).

Comment: Normally flags and arguments can be moved around freely. Just try it :-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Only if the application in question uses GNUs questionable way of rearranging  the command line arguments. Options should otherwise always come before operands.

Comment: @Kusalananda  I've been running the GNU software stack for close to 25 years now, so perhaps my worldview is somewhat skewed :-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I was cautious about just trying it - don't want to mess anything up.

Comment: You will definitely **not** mess anything up if you try. Actually the second way of invocation looks more natural and logical.

Comment: @Kusalananda Can you point me in the direction of docs that further explain why options should always come before operands?

Comment: @knot22 It's a POSIX guideline: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01  In this particular case it also matters whether `--global` is an option to `sudo`, to `npr` or to the `install` sub-command of `npr`.  Moving the option around freely on the command line would definitely make a difference.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I think you mean "GNU's useful way".

Comment: You don't want to move arguments around freely with `find`, `sed` and many others. It matters a whole lot. If in doubt, refer to documentation and act accordingly.

Comment: @ilkkachu I dunno. GNU `rm` errors out on `rm one -two three` while other `rm` implementations correctly removes the three files `one`, `-two` and `three` as intended.

Comment: @Kusalananda, aren't filenames with a dash in front one reason we tell people to use `--` or `./-foo`, right? If you were only removing that one file, you'd have to do `rm -- -two` in any version `rm`. But the point where the GNU behaviour is useful, is when you realize in the middle of the command line that you needed another option, or run the command once, and then realize you needed to add `-f` or `-l`. I honestly imagine they've made it that way because someone found it useful, but then people could complain about all other GNU extensions too.

Comment: And well, there's always `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` for people who like to rely on the standard closer than the default is.

Comment: Really the title should match the body: "the npm command" not "a command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page for `npm(1)`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) shows:

> ```
>  Synopsis
>       npm <command> [args]
> ```

It doesn't say much else, so all we can deduce is that `install` is the `<command>` and must come before the `[args]`.  The `[args]` are `expo-cli` and `--global`.

Let's inspect the `install` command to see if we can get more details.  [`npm-install(1)`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) says:

> ```
> Synopsis
>     ...
>     npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
>     ...
>
>     aliases: npm i, npm add
>     common options: [-P|--save-prod|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional] [-E|--save-exact]
>                     [-B|--save-bundle] [--no-save] [--dry-run]
> ```

It doesn't say anything about order.  This starts to make us think order doesn't matter.  If we scroll down we see things like:

> ```
> The  --tag  argument will apply to all of the specified install targets. 
> The -g or --global argument will cause npm to install the package globally 
> rather than locally.  See npm help folders.
> ```

Ok... so order is never mentioned in the man page, but we see that `--tag` applies to all targets.  They felt that it was important to mention in the man page because if someone tries to install several packages and specify a tag, they might assume that the `--tag` flag applies only to the package before or after.  That's not the case, options apply to everything.  If options apply to everything, then **order is probably not important**.

Note that all of the examples they give in the man page put the package before the flag.

You could try it out:

```
npm install sax --global expo-cli
```

Check if they are both installed globally (I bet they are).

If you want to install several packages, some local, some global, then I'd suggest taking the safe approach and using two separate commands because it isn't defined in the documentation and therefore behavior could change.

Comment: With _other_ commands, the order would matter. The trivial example is any command that provides a `--quiet` and a `--verbose` option.  Usually, a later option would override any earlier conflicting option.  I understood the question as if the give command only was an _example_.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Especially for conflicting arguments like `--quiet --verbose`, it's best not to make assumptions when things aren't documented and just avoid relying on undocumented behaviour.  In this case, I would guess `--verbose` takes priority, but I have no reason to be confident in that guess.

Comment: @Kusalananda But why the order matters in case of `--verbose`? Can you expand a little bit about "override any earlier conflicting option".

Comment: @adosar A command may provide an option for becoming _quiet_, `-q`, or _verbose_, `-v`.  The command, when invoked as `some-command -q -v` would then be expected to be _verbose_, while `some-command -v -q` would be expected to be _quiet_.  The later option overrides the earlier conflicting option.

Comment: @Kusalananda For example, `tar -xfv` won't work but `tar -xvf` will. In that case what is the difference?

Comment: @adosar Your example is different because the `-f` option to `tar` takes an argument. In the first command, `tar` is asked to extract the archive called `v` (`tar -x -f v`). In the second command, `tar` is given the option `-v` while `-f` is _missing its argument_ (`tar -x -v -f`). This example is not the same as we have discussed in the comments to this answer. It seems to instead be about a misunderstanding of what `-f` does when used with the `tar` command, or possibly about the fact that short options may be written together as a single string.